# Person who never makes excuses

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

How do you express a person who never makes excuses under any difficult situations?

Example:

> When he faced difficult situations, he never backed off or never complained. He was such a _____ person./ He was a ____.

Comment: Responsible can fit, because responsible people don't make excuses. But I still find your request unclear: what kind of excuses are you talking about? For what purpose would these excuses be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idiomatically, a common term for this type of behavior is *stand-up*. Here is the entry for that adjective (in its relevant sense) in Barbara Kipfer & Robert Chapman, *Dictionary of American Slang*, fourth edition (2007):

> **stand-up *adj*** Courageous and personally accountable; bold; GUTSY  Most often used in the expression *stand-up guy* : *He handled the humiliating defeat like a stand-up guy*/ *And he's very, very stand-up* (1841+) ... {adjective sense perhaps fr *stand up and be counted* ["To announce and be accountable for one's convictions, opinions, etc.; not be afraid to speak up"]}

In the example sentences you give, the fill-in-the-blank terms would be as follows:

> When he faced difficult situations, he never backed off or never complained. He was such a **stand-up** person./ He was a **stand-up guy**.

Answer (score 3):

***Stoical***, perhaps?

Resembling a Stoic in austerity, indifference to pleasure and pain, repression of all feeling, and the like.(OED)

Answer (score 1):

***Resilient,*** maybe? You can say "he was a resilient person." It's in the spectrum of what you're looking for, so it may or may not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [synonyms for determined](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/determined). Examples include:

- resolved
- single-minded
- tenacious
- persevering
- unwavering

I think these words more generally describe someone who doesn't give up, but someone who doesn't give up is much less likely to make excuses than someone who does give up.